# struts.xml mapping problem

Tags: java, struts2

> type: Status report
>
> message:There is no Action mapped for
>   namespace / and action name add.
>
> description: The requested resource
>   (There is no Action mapped for
>   namespace / and action name add.) is
>   not available.

---

struts.xml file is below and it create with web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation"
    value="false" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />

<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">

    <action name="add"
        class="net.vanita.contact.view.ContactAction" method="add">
        <result name="success" type="chain">index</result>
        <result name="input" type="chain">index</result>
    </action>

    <action name="delete"
        class="net.vanita.contact.view.ContactAction" method="delete">
        <result name="success" type="chain">index</result>
    </action>

    <action name="index"
        class="net.vanita.contact.view.ContactAction">
        <result name="success">index.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

web .xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">    
<display-name>StrutsHelloWorld</display-name>    
<welcome-file-list>   
 <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>   
</welcome-file-list>  
<filter> 
 <filter-name>struts2</filter-name> 
  <filter-class> 
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher 
  </filter-class> 
</filter>     
 <filter-mapping> 
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name> 
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
 </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

ContactAction.java is below

```
package net.vanita.contact.view;

import java.util.List;
import net.vanita.contact.controller.ContactManager;
import net.vanita.contact.model.Contact;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class ContactAction extends ActionSupport {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9149826260758390091L;
    private Contact contact;
    private List<Contact> contactList;
    private Long id;
    private ContactManager linkController;

    public ContactAction() {
        linkController = new ContactManager();
    }

    public String execute() {
        if (null != contact) {
            linkController.add(getContact());
        }
        this.contactList = linkController.list();
        System.out.println(contactList);
        System.out.println(contactList.size());
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String add() {
        System.out.println(getContact());
        try {
            linkController.add(getContact());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String delete() {
        linkController.delete(getId());
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public Contact getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public List<Contact> getContactList() {
        return contactList;
    }

    public void setContact(Contact contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public void setContactList(List<Contact> contactsList) {
        this.contactList = contactsList;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

index.jsp file is below

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%> 
<html> 
    <head>     
        <title>Contact Manager - Struts2 Hibernate Example</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
    <h1>Contact Manager</h1> 
<s:actionerror/> 

<s:form action="/add" method="post"> 
    <s:textfield name="contact.id" label="Id"/> 
    <s:textfield name="contact.firstName" label="Firstname"/> 
    <s:textfield name="contact.lastName" label="Lastname"/> 
    <s:textfield name="contact.emailId" label="Email"/> 
    <s:textfield name="contact.cellNo" label="Cell No."/> 
    <s:textfield name="contact.website" label="Homepage"/> 
    <s:textfield name="contact.birthDate" label="Birthdate"/> 
    <s:submit value="Add Contact" align="center"/> 
</s:form> 

<h2>Contacts</h2> 
<table> 
<tr> 
    <th>Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Cell No.</th> 
    <th>Birthdate</th> 
    <th>Homepage</th> 
    <th>Delete</th> 
</tr> 
<s:iterator value="contactList" var="contact"> 
    <tr> 
        <td><s:property value="lastName"/>, <s:property value="firstName"/> </td> 
        <td><s:property value="emailId"/></td> 
        <td><s:property value="cellNo"/></td> 
        <td><s:property value="birthDate"/></td> 
        <td><a href="<s:property value="website"/>">link</a></td> 
        <td><a href="delete?id=<s:property value="id"/>">delete</a></td> 
    </tr> 
</s:iterator> 
</table> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: can you please add your web.xml ?>

Comment: Does net.vanita.contact.view.ContactAction extend org.apache.struts.actionAction?

Comment: public class ContactAction extends ActionSupport

Comment: can you provide stack trace..and you net.vanita.contact.view.ContactAction class

Comment: have you configured name space correctly in the jsp file..?i have doubt since the name space you have defined in the mapping is not root name space.can you also show code from your JSP?

Answer (score 0):

why you using

```
<s:form action="/add" method="post">
```

where you can achieve this simply by using

```
<s:form action="add" method="post">
```

problem is that struts2 framework unable to find your action in the given namespace.